# Two Task Common vs TWO_TASK variable

Tags: oracle

Is there a relationship between [Two Task Common](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/net/doc/NWUS233/ch2.htm#twotask) and the environment variable [TWO_TASK](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:89412348059)?

TTC is part of the overall Oracle*Net stack and "provides character set and data type conversion between different character sets or formats between client and server"

The Oracle environment variable TWO_TASK is used to connect to a remote database via SQL Net.

For the names to be so similar and both to be involved in the Oracle network architecture I feel there must be some relationship. Does TTC also manage this remote connection piece?